# Request for Reactive Server response with image content type Sample

Tags: spring-webflux

I'm starting a new project and adopting spring webflux as reactive rest framework. I have a use case that return captcha image at the backend. I have a sample code as below which generate captcha image and return with spring framework but now I have no idea how to return the image with reactive way.

This is my use case in Spring MVC way:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/captcha/{id:.+}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody byte[] captcha(@PathVariable("id") String captchaId,  HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception{

      try{
         byte [] captchaImg = (byte[])cacheService.getValue(captchaId,    AuthConstants.CACHE_CAPTCHA_IMG_KEY);

         return captchaImg;
      }catch(Exception e){
        res.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        return null;
      }
}
```

In reactive way which is failure code as below:

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> captchaImage(ServerRequest request) {

        return Mono.just(request.pathVariable("id"))
                .flatMap(id->cacheService.getValue(id, AuthConstant.CACHE_CAPTCHA_IMG_KEY))
                .flatMap(captchaImage-> {
                    System.out.println("img:"+captchaImage);
                    return ServerResponse
                            .ok()
                            .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(captchaImage));
                });

    }
```

This code is failure and I can't find any information to get idea how to do it.

I need your help. Appreciate that you can provide some snippet code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found an answer.

```
public Mono<ServerResponse> captchaImage(ServerRequest request) {
        return Mono.just(request.pathVariable("id"))

                //get the image from redis in byte[]
                .flatMap(id->genericHashOperations.opsForHash().get(id,AuthConstant.CACHE_CAPTCHA_IMG_KEY)
                .flatMap(cimg->{

                    byte[] i = (byte[]) cimg;

                    //use data Buffer to wrap the image in byte array
                    DataBuffer buffer = new DefaultDataBufferFactory().wrap(i);

                    return ServerResponse
                            .ok()
                            .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
                            .body(BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(Flux.just(buffer)));
                }));
    }
```